# Manipulate Data from Google Sheets with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets

I've been Googling and searching around all over the web trying to find specific information on how to use Google Sheets as a data source in WordPress and manipulate that data into pre-existing ShortCode.

I have been asked to try and figure out how to store pricing information inside of a Google Sheet and plug that data into existing ShortCode for a site that uses a Cron to update the data at set intervals. The goal is to have a customer access the Google Sheet and update their prices when they want and then have the site update with those price changes and maintain the look of their site without using basic Google Sheets templates.

I've found a few various solutions that are close, but none of them go into manipulating the data how I want. They all are basically just default templates of what a Google table looks like. I essentially want to query the data from the sheet and plug it into the ShortCode.

I am not looking for anyone to write the code for me, but am merely looking to be pushed in the right direction for how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a pretty old post and you've probably found a solution already, but I was looking for something very similar just last week and came across [Inline Google Spreadsheet Viewer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-google-spreadsheet-viewer/).  It is amazingly robust and may take some research (if you're not familiar with JSON and datatables like I'm not) to get used to, but I think anyone looking to use a google spreadsheet as their "database" will find this plugin incredibly useful.